# Permission Not Granted

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, permissions

I'm trying to get access to the system settings, but it seems my method that requests the permission always returns false. My knowledge is limited so I don't really know where to start to fix it

```
private void getPermissions(){
    boolean value;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        value = Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext());
          if(value) {
              success = true;
          }else{
              Intent intent = new 
                            Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
              intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + 
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
              startActivity(intent);
           }
      }
}
```

the getPermission() is called upon the creation of the app.

Comment: where does it return false? on `Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext());`?

Comment: So I debugged the method, **value** returns _false_. And an alert comes up sometimes saying "Sourcecode Doesn't Match Bytecode" if that would be any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] permissionsRequired = new String{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

//on button click
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[0])
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[1])
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[2])
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermission();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, permissionsRequired, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
}
```

Comment: the code above looks valid, but I'm trying to get access to the system settings. not the camera or any other resources.